# How ngRepeat works in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm preparing a presentation for a talk so I drew a diagram on how ngRepeat works. The focus of the talk is ngRepeats role in performance pitfalls but I'm not sure if everything is right in the diagram or if I missed something.

Are there more loops in ngRepeat that could affect the performance, 
how does a change in the filter with a model affect the reevaluation of the ngRepeat(does it just trigger the watch the same way as the model/array change ?)

[image: how does ngRepeat work]